# Shared istio egress gateway in multi-cluster/multi-primary mesh

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

We are trying to setup an egress gateway in a multi-cluster/multi-primary mesh
configuration where the egress gateway is located in only one cluster but used from both.

[diagram of desired setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92eav.png)

The use case is that the clusters are in different network zones and we want to be able
to route traffic to one zone transparently to the clients in the other zone.

We followed [this guide](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/) in one cluster and it worked fine. However we have trouble setting up the `VirtualService` in the second cluster
to use the egress gateway in the first cluster.

When deploying the following virtual service to the second cluster we get 503 with cluster_not_found.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: direct-cnn-through-egress-gateway
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  gateways:
  - istio-egressgateway
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: edition.cnn.com
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
```

The endpoints proxy config on a pod in the second cluster misses the `istio-egressgateway.istio-gateways.svc.cluster.local`
endpoints (all other services are discovered and directed to the eastwest gateway of the other cluster).
We believe that this is the reason that this `VirtualService` doesn't work in the second cluster.

As a workaround we could redirect the egress traffic to the ingress gateway of the first cluster but this
has the disadvantage that the traffic leaves and re-enters the mesh which probably has an impact on tracing and monitoring.

Is it currently possible to setup a single egress gateway that can be used by all clusters in the mesh or do we have to go with the workaround?

Comment: Hi @Tobias Henkel, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you tell me how did you deploy your cluster (bare-metal, any cloud providor)? Did you try to use [ServiceEntry](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) instead of VirtualService?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. My test setup consists of two EKS clusters in AWS, but the target is a combination of EKS clusters and onprem k8s clusters on openstack. Regarding the ServiceEntry, do you mean in cluster B instead of the VirtualService and with fixed endpoints listed that target A's eastwest gateway?

Comment: I think you should use `Service Entry` on both clusters. Look at this [concept](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/) of multicluster configuration. In this case you can also use [admiral](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/admiral) to automate traffic routing. [Here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary_multi-network/) you can find another concept, how to create multi-cluster configuration. It could be very similar situation to yours.

Comment: I will include one more example for you of multi cluster [load balancing](https://www.istiobyexample.dev/locality-load-balancing). I have found also very nice tutorials to create Cross-Cluster Application (but for GKE). You can look [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-a-multi-cluster-service-mesh-on-gke-using-replicated-control-plane-architecture) and [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/istio-multi-burst/#0)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed we've created the multi-cluster deployment using [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary_multi-network/). Cross cluster workload of normal services works fine. My problem is just getting the traffic to the egress gateway routed via the eastwest gateway. I've successfully managed to route the traffic via the other ingress gateway though using a similar approach like [here](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/proxying-legacy-services-using-egress-gateways/).

Admiral sounds interesting, I will look into it.

Comment: So, @Tobias Henkel, is your question resolved? :)

Comment: So I did some more experiments now. I got it to work fine with the service entry if I target the ingress gateway on ports 80/443 which then dispatches further to the mesh external services. However if I target the eastwest gateway on 15443 (which would put less dependencies on the network setup due to a single port) the requests are stuck on the eastwest gateway. What I did not understand is why the dispatching works for mesh internal services.
This is the log ```[2021-05-26T14:44:27.949Z] "- - -" 0 UH - - "-" 0 0 9 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - - 10.215.237.170:15443 10.215.238.254:32006 - -`

Comment: in the log I can see port 32006. Please explain what it is supposed to be responsible for. Another question, are you getting any error when you target the eastwest gateway on 15443? Any response code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments the solution should works as below:

To create a multi-cluster deployment you can use [this tutorial](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary_multi-network/). In this situation cross cluster workload of normal services works fine. However, there is a problem with getting the traffic to the egress gateway routed via the eastwest gateway. This can be solved with  [this example](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/proxying-legacy-services-using-egress-gateways/).
You should also change `kind: VirtualService` to `kind: ServiceEntry` in both clusters.

Like [Tobias Henkel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13372385/tobias-henkel) mentioned:

> I got it to work fine with the service entry if I target the ingress gateway on ports 80/443 which then dispatches further to the mesh external services.

---

You can also use [Admiral](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/admiral) to automate traffic routing.

See also:

- [multi cluster mesh automation using Admiral](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/)
- [multi cluster service mesh od GKE](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-a-multi-cluster-service-mesh-on-gke-using-replicated-control-plane-architecture)
- [tutorial on GKE to create similar situation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/istio-multi-burst/#0)